# Global optimisation - Error bound on NMaximize?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, constraint

Is it possible to obtain an error bound on `NMaximize`? e.g. convert the number returned by `NMaximize` into a rigorous upper bound on the function being maximised. In my problem, involving maximising a multivariate polynomial function on a sphere,  I am certain that the result returned by `NMaximize` is the "correct" one, i.e. the actual global maximum up to few decimals.

Comment: Are you asking if you can guarantee that the result of NMaximize is a global maximum? That depends on the nature of your function, typically. If that's not your question, unfortunately I am not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: That is what I am asking. I should say I need this for a pure mathematics paper. I am certain that the value found is the global maximum, but I need to quantify this somehow.

Comment: The function is a degree 6 homogenous polynomial in 3 variables. Using other methods, I can solve for all of the stationary points and thus find all local maxima, so I know that NMaximise picked out the correct local maximum.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that NMaximise is a lot faster than the procedure I've used to find all of the stationary points.

Comment: The documentation of `NMaximize` states that "If the function and the constraints are linear, `NMaximize` can always find global maxima, over both real and integer values.". Does that apply to your case?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't - my function is a polynomial of degree 6, so a sum of terms like u1^6,u1^5u2,... and so on, and my constraint is the sphere u1^2+u2^2+u3^2=1. The function is not "wild" -  all of its coefficients are smallish real numbers, all about the same size.

Comment: Can you present the optimization problem you asked about in this forum?

Comment: Any chance you can cast the polynomial as a quadratic form in the u_j?

Comment: I got your point. Looking in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalOperationsOnFunctions.html , I find the "Controlling the Precision of Results" section. which may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which may be useful.
Making use of the command of Maple

```
restart;0.001*randpoly([x, y, z], homogeneous, degree = 6);
```

, I obtain a random homogeneous polynomial of degree 6 `-0.073*x^5*y + 0.097*x^4*z^2 - 0.062*x^2*y^2*z^2 - 0.056*x^2*z^4 + 
 0.087*y^5*z`. Sorry, but I don't find how to do that in Mathematica in the Mathematica documentation.

Next,

```
p = -0.073*x^5*y + 0.097*x^4*z^2 - 0.062*x^2*y^2*z^2 - 0.056*x^2*z^4 + 0.087*y^5*z;
NMaximize[{p, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y, z}]
(*{0.019035, {x -> 0.904672, y -> -0.392777, z -> -0.165211}}*)
Maximize[{p, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y, z}]
(*{0.019035, {x -> 0.904672, y -> -0.392777, z -> -0.165211}}*)
```

The result is not optimal, as

```
Maximize[{Rationalize[-0.073*x^5*y + 0.097*x^4*z^2 - 
0.062*x^2*y^2*z^2 - 0.056*x^2*z^4 + 0.087*y^5*z], x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y, z}]
(*{29/(576 Sqrt[5]), {x -> 0, y -> -Sqrt[(5/6)], z -> -(1/Sqrt[6])}}*)
N[29/(576 Sqrt[5])]
(*0.022516*)
```

shows.

Comment: The result is confirmed by the command of Maple `DirectSearch:-GlobalOptima(-0.073*x^5*y + 0.097*x^4*z^2 - 0.062*x^2*y^2*z^2 - 0.056*x^2*z^4 + 0.087*y^5*z, {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1}, maximize,tolerances = 10^(-10))` which results in `[0.0225159622729918, [x = 2.38830199851266*10^(-6), y = 0.912870908714871, z = 0.408248336207732], 1454]`.

Comment: The same approach works for a dense random polynomial `q = 0.062*y^3*z*x^2 - 0.083*y*z^3*x^2 - 0.010*y^2*z^2*x^2 - 
   0.017*y^3*z^2*x - 0.075*y^4*z*x + 0.097*y^2*z*x^3 - 
   0.062*y*z^2*x^3 - 0.044*y*z^4*x + 0.087*y*z*x^4 + 
   0.071*y^2*z^3*x - 0.007*z^6 - 0.092*y^6 - 0.007*x^6 + 
   0.022*z*x^5 - 0.055*y*x^5 - 0.094*z^2*x^4 - 0.056*y^2*x^4 - 
   0.073*y^3*x^3 - 0.004*z^4*x^2 - 0.082*y^4*x^2 + 0.080*z^5*x - 
   0.010*y^5*x - 0.040*y*z^5 + 0.042*y^2*z^4 - 0.050*y^3*z^3 + 
   0.023*y^4*z^2 + 0.075*y^5*z;`.

Comment: In some cases `Maximize[{Rationalize[q, 0.0000000001], x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y, 
  z}]` works better.

Comment: If the constraint is changed to <= instead of == it will give a better result. Offhand I do not know the reason but I have a guess or two.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Thank you for your interest. It's clear: if we replace `==` by `<=`, we extend a feasible set and the optimal value increased. However, if the optimal value is attained on the boundary of the feasible set (as in my example with `DirectSearch`), the result is the same. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need, supplying by a code.

Comment: The system is homogeneous so the max has to be either at the origin (if it is negative definite) or on the boundary. The question is why extension by a region that cannot (in this case) contain the max actually seems to help. As I noted, I have some idea, but not a definite answer for that. `DirectSearch` by the way is basically using calls to `FindMaximum`.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau  Sorry, I understand nothing in your comment, but I feel it's great.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems like NMaximise fails more frequently than I thought. Like I said, in my class of examples it does find the global maximum, but it seems that proving that will require actual work instead of playing around with Mathematica.